# PHP parse var_dump json

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a script that get data from a JSON-API.

`echo var_dump(json_decode($result, true));` this displays:

```
hejarray(1) { 
  ["items"]=> array(2) {
        ["item"]=> array(1) { 
              [0]=> array(23) { 
                    ["newsdeskML"]=> string(3) "2.1"                                                                           
                    ["type_of_media"]=> string(12) "pressrelease"       
                    ["language"]=> string(2) "sv" 
                    ["source_id"]=> string(5) "47784"             
                    ["source_name"]=> string(24) "Sverige AB" 
                    ["pressroom_name"]=> string(24) "Sverige AB" 
                    ["pressroom"]=> string(2) "se" 
                    ["pressroom_id"]=> string(5) "53128"             
                    ["organization_number"]=> string(11) "556052-5833" 
                    ["id"]=> string(6) "968485" 
                    ["url"]=> string(126) "xx.com" 
                    ["published_at"]=> string(19) "2014-03-05 08:08:33"               ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2014-03-05 08:08:33"       
                    ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2014-03-05 08:08:34"       
                    ["header"]=> string(56) "header header" 
                    ["summary"]=> string(277) "text text".........
```

If i only want to echo the content in `["summary"]=> string(277) "text text"` how can this be done?

EDIT
Full json reponse, had to remove contest as it's sensetive data:

```
{  
   "items":{  
      "item":[  
         {  
            "newsdeskML":"2.1",
            "type_of_media":"pressrelease",
            "language":"sv",
            "source_id":"47784",
            "source_name":"",
            "pressroom_name":"",
            "pressroom":"se",
            "pressroom_id":"",
            "organization_number":"",
            "id":"968485",
            "url":"",
            "published_at":"2014-03-05 08:08:33",
            "created_at":"2014-03-05 08:08:33",
            "updated_at":"2014-03-05 08:08:34",
            "header":"",
            "summary":"",
            "body":""
         },
         {  
            "related_items":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This gives the same php output i posted at first:

$var = json_decode($result, true);
echo var_dump($var);

But echo var_dump($var['items']); gives null

Comment: it doesn't seem a valid json that try it here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @Michelem changed to the correct one now, messed up copy pasting when i removed some data not to be shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it with:

```
$var = json_decode($result, true);

echo $var['items']['item'][0]['summary']
```

Comment: can you show us the `$result` string without the `json_decode`?

Comment: {
"items": {
"item": [
{
"summary": "text",

Comment: No please, edit your question and add the full string. (you can use pastebin.net if the string is really long)

Answer (score 2):

`json_decode` returns an associative array when you specify the second parameter to `true` (like you did). So you can basically just go with:

```
$json_object = json_decode($result, true);
echo $json_object["path"]["to"]["your"]["property"];
```